# C++ Array of Different General Types

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Consider this code:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(std::vector<T> arr) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doSomething(std::vector<int> { 1, 5, 7 });
}
```

In this example, a template is being used quite regularly. An array of three integers is being passed into a function which has a paramater of an array of type `T`'s, general types. It is then specified that they are of type `int` here: `std::vector<int> { 1, 5, 7 }`.

What I would like to do is to initialize the `std::vector` to contain three different types. Something like this:

```
doSomething(std::vector<T> { 1, "Hi", 2.7f });
```

Here, there is no specified type, and the `std::vector` doesn't only contain integers. Is there any way to do such a thing? Thanks!

Comment: (I think) You could fake it with a lot of classes, but that would be terrible code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to do that with `std::vector`. The template argument is unique.

Check [std::tuple](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) which can do what you want.

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, float>
```

If you need more genericity you will have to do something like this :

```
template<typename U, typename V, typename W>
void doSomething(std::tuple<U,V,W> t) { ... }
```

If you want a tuple with an arbitrary number of elements, you must use variadic templates then:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void doSomething(std::tuple<Ts...> data) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As mentionned by Guillaume variadic templates answer your question but I won't recommended it to you for the moment. See [std::tuple foreach implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51407/stdtuple-foreach-implementation)  to iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how C++ works. C++ is a statically-typed language. The types of all variables must be declared at compile time.

Other languages, like Perl, Python, Javascript, and others, are dynamically-typed. The type of an object is determined at runtime, so the equivalent array construct in dynamically-typed languages could have values of different types.